# Who handles the customs when shipping to a package forwarder address in another country?

Tags: usa, eu, shopping, shipping

I ordered a product from a US store, but I had to use a package forwarder ([Shipito](https://shipito.com)), because the US store didn't ship directly to Romania. That store was however shipping to Austria, and I thought that I might save some money by having it shipped there first and then ship it again to Romania.

After tracking the package for two weeks, it seems like now it is stuck in Vienna. It's been there for over a week now. Nobody called or emailed me during this period of time, and I suspect that the package is stuck at the customs office. I talked to Shipito and they said that all customs-related issues have to be handled by customers. I emailed the US store but they didn't reply yet.

What will happen to my package? Will it be shipped back to the US, or abandoned, based on this annoying coordination issue? The Austrian customs office didn't contact me, though they could have - my email and phone number are on the package.

Comment: First, I don't think this is on-topic here, as it's definitely not related to travel. Having a parcel shipped from a the US to an EU address necessarily involves customs. The procedure for paying import taxes and duties depends on the carrier (mostly on whether it goes through the national postal services or through independent couriers). You apparently have a tracking number for the parcel, that often enables you to pay import taxes and duties, though it's more frequent for couriers rather than through the postal services. Customs nearly never contact you directly, it's the carrier's job.

Comment: I didn't know that the carrier is the one who always handle this. Thanks, @jcaron.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about travel.

Comment: [Shipto's FAQ](https://www.shipito.com/en/help/faq/customs): _**Do I have to pay taxes and customs fees if a package arrives to Shipito from out of the country? How would I pay?**_
Yes, you are responsible for paying all customs clearance, duties or taxes. These can be paid in one of two ways: Pay directly: Contact the package courier directly to pay. Pay COD: If you would like to pay upon delivery, contact Shipito 2-3 days before your package arrives and provide us with the courier's name, amount due and the tracking number. Lastly, please deposit sufficient funds into your account to...

Comment: ... _complete the COD payment.
If you have not paid duties and taxes in advance or you don't have enough funds in your account to cover charges, packages are subject to refusal and may be returned to sender._

Comment: So check with the carrier. Either you can pay them directly to release the package and have it delivered, or they expect payment at the time they deliver it (COD), in which case you have to arrange that with Shipito (but it should have been done before, not after). But you probably didn't pick the right combination, usually one uses such forwarding service to deliver from a merchant in the same country, and then you have customs when it goes from the forwarder to you, that makes things much easier.